# Easiest way to retrieve a single field from database with Fat-Free Framework?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

What is the easiest way to retrieve the value of a single field from a MySQL database using Fat-Free Framework? I have been able to do it with the following code which returns an array but am wondering how to improve this:

```
$result = $db->exec('SELECT id FROM admins WHERE username = ?',$f3->get('POST.username'));
```

This query returns the `id` field that we are seeking in an array which is accessible via `$result[0]['id']` - can we avoid assigning this to an array and read it directly to a string variable?

Comment: *Cursor* is a great way to get data from the database, I would argue that the memory footprint of it is larger though than a simple *exec*. And though the framework allows it, it isn't always necessary and comes down to the definition of **Easiest**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this is an old question but I ran into the same problem recently and came up with the findone() function. I wanted to share it as it had not been mentioned before in case anyone else is looking for a solution.

```
$f3=\Base::instance();
$f3->set('DB',new DB\SQL('sqlite:db/database.sqlite'));
$admins = new \DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'), 'admins');
$username = $admins->findone(['username = ?', $f3->get('POST.username')])->username;
```

Line 1-3 are just preliminaries. You'll need a table mapper to use this function. Line 4 is a one-liner which will set the $username to hold the actual value of the username.

Comment: Coming back to this years later, this no longer works. It does as long as there is something found. Otherwise it gives a 'Attempt to read property "username" on bool'. F3 now returns false on the find so you can't chain the column anymore.

Comment: It still works when running in php 7.3 but in 8.1 it gives above error.

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://github.com/f3-factory/fatfree-core/issues/356

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which version of PHP you're using you could possibly do this..

```
$result = $db->exec('SELECT id FROM admins WHERE username = ?',$f3->get('POST.username'))[0]['id'];
```

or if you were using pure PDO you could use `fetchColumn()`, but you're using a framework. The only way to change the returned value is to edit the framework code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Cursor/Mapper](http://fatfreeframework.com/sql-mapper).

Something Like:

```
\Base::instance()->set('DB',new DB\SQL('sqlite:db/database.sqlite'));
$admins_mapper = new \DB\SQL\Mapper(\Base::instance()->get('DB'), 'admins');
$admin = $admin_mapper->load(array('username = ?', \Base::instance()->get('POST.username'));
```

You can also use [Cortex](https://github.com/ikkez/f3-cortex) which is build on top of Cursor.